# Get latest file trailing number in php

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

I have something like this in my directory:

```
slider-1.jpg
slider-2.png
slider-4.gif
slider-8.png
slider-11.gif
```

Now is there a way to get the last trailing number of "slider" images ?
I need to get this so the next uploaded image should be named slider-12.xxx

I tried for each loop, but it obviously gets me slider-3 as a next name which is false in my case :)

ok, here is how I did it

```
foreach ($files as $filename) {
    $filesarr[]= $filename;
    $namearr = explode('.', $filename); //I had to grab this piece as well during the project, so this is main reason not usin Louis proposal.... i needed that array for something else...
    $numbers = explode('-', $namearr[1]);
    $compare[]=$numbers[2];   

}
sort($compare, SORT_NUMERIC); 
$assigned_number = end($compare) + 1;
```

Comment: If it's exclusive to uploads (ie no one will be manually adding files to the folder) it would be easier to just track the last number used, eg write it to a text file, and read/increment at next upload.

Comment: yes, there will be uploads from all over... manually, ajax's etc.. Louis's solution works great, but I've used different approach... I exploded files, garbed the set of strings before final dot and dash... and since in each case that will be a number, I just added +1 .... but Louis solution is better... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$max = 0;
foreach($files AS $file) {
    $max = max($max, filter_var($file, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
}
$max++;
```

or this:

```
natcasesort($files);
$max = filter_var(array_slice($files, -1), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) + 1;
```

Comment: yes, because he needs the next id for the uploaded file to be one higher than the highest existing id. So we'll take the biggest and add one.

Comment: Right Ok, I misunderstood the OP so was confused by this solution.